# Can I add numbers to int value instead of changing it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, int

Is it possible to add numbers to the total value of an `int` cell instead of set its value? Correctly I'm using a list and I and things are getting weird.. the list is `<int>` list and its value is jumping into random numbers without any reason. I think that changing the count type (from list into int) will solve it. (c#. visual studio 2013).

Comment: Yes. (If you want a more detailed answer you should provide more details yourself.)

Comment: `I'm using a list and I and things are getting weird.. ` Can you share these weird things with us since we don't have crystal ball to see what is happening.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Please add some code, it will help demonstrate what you want and what is going on.

Comment: ok. I'm building a game. and I want to add +1 every time the main hero's picturebox is Intersects with another picturebox. and that picture bbox is empty and invisible. I used list<int> to contain the numbers. I called it "level" so I wrote: "if (bloom.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rightborder.Bounds))
            {
                level.Add(1);
                bloom.Location = new Point(850, 500); 
            }   '' and then it didn't said that level = 1 at the debugger. it said so only at the firs time. at the secend and the third it became high random numbers. like 40 or 769. ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look so hard to me...?

```
int variable = 10;    // start with 10 points
variable++;           // add 1
variable += 3         // add 3
```